# What's the difference between FETCH NEXT and FETCH (without NEXT) when dealing with CURSOR in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, loops, while-loop, cursor, fetch

What's the difference between `FETCH NEXT` and `FETCH` (without `NEXT`) when dealing with `CURSOR` in MySQL?

And can I use the global variable `@@FETCH_STATUS` to replace the following verbose sentence? --

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_done = 1;
```

Just as:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 DO
    ......
END WHILE;
```

It seems more elegant and simpler.

Comment: MYSQL is not sql server FETCH NEXT is not a valid statement in MYSQL. The MYSQL statement is FETCH NEXT FROM which is a more verbose form of FIND. @@FETCH_STATUS is not a valid MYSQL statement the MYSQL way of catching and eof cursor is the continue handler.

Comment: Thank you very much! And I didn't express myself clearly. What I mean is: what's the difference of `FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO ...` and `FETCH FROM cursor INTO ...`. Are there any differences between with and without `NEXT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is there's no difference between them. They are totally same.